# FBX Export: Extra Frame & Loop Glitch

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

I'm required to export animated models from blender to fbx, and while I've managed to exported animated models to fbx format, I'm having two issues I can't seem to crack:

1. The animation is looped with the first and last frames identical, however, when I reimport the animated model (after exporting as an fbx), there is a sliiight jump in the model when going from the last frame to the first (as it loops around). Would you know how I could fix this?
2. There is always one more frame in the exported animation than what is in the original blender file - how could I solve this? is this normal?

Thanks!

Comment: If you disable All Actions and Nla Tracks in the exporter window the animation will be as long as the play length in the editor.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still had an extra frame :, good thing is that it's hardly noticeable in a loop, but the little glitch is still there, hmmm